# When the response time is too long, I receive a proxy error

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have a process in the model that send SMS to more than 1000 users and updates the Database accordingly based on the response. This process take a while to complete. By the time the response comes back. I see a 502 proxy error in the browser.Reason : Error reading from remote server
How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. I had to change my apache configuration for this. I was using ProxyPass and had to put a timeout for 10 minutes and keepalive on to my proxypass.

Found my solution here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/185894/proxy-error-502-reason-error-reading-from-remote-server-with-apache-2-2-3-de

Comment: You might want to mark your own answer as 'accepted', just so the question appears as 'answered'.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, a timeout could be occurring either:

1. between your application server and the remote SMS gateway, or
2. between your browser and the application server.

### If the error is between your application server and the remote messaging gateway

- If you are connecting to the SMS sending server through a proxy you control, try increasing the connection timeout for the proxy
- If you have maximum execution time set on your server, that might kill a page render after a certain amount of time.
- Try sending in smaller batches to reduce the duration of the request to the messaging server.

Reducing the request duration (e.g. by sending messages in smaller batches) will reduce the risk of a timeout at either the remote server or an intermediate. It also has the advantage that you can update your progress as each batch sends. 
It will make it easier to diagnose if a particular recipient phone number is causing an error on the remote server by narrowing down the list of possible problem numbers.

### If the error is between your browser and your application

You might be running the message sending from the same process that generates the response to your browser. This will preventing a page from being constructed and returned to you quickly, and so either your remote server or an intermediate server may cause a time-out while you wait for the message sending to finish.

Rather than waiting until a long-running operations has finished to return a page to your browser, it can be helpful to start using a message or job queuing system (e.g. [Gearman](https://metacpan.org/release/Gearman), [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)). These systems allow you to put long-running tasks into a queue, so that a page can quickly generated and returned. By having the long-running tasks include progress updates (e.g. writing progress to the database), you can have a page that will show you the progress of the task as it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple you have to just pass with your proxy Keepalive=On parameter

Eg:

```
http://localhost:5000/ Keepalive=On
```